# Show custom content in Main Page Summary

Tags: theming, ubercart

I have a site using Ubercart that shows product summaries on the main page (I believe these are called teasers).  Each product has a voting widget provided by [Vote Up/Down](http://drupal.org/project/vote_up_down) on its actual node/page.  I've copied page.tpl.php to page-front.tpl.php because I want to add a small block or box that shows the number of upvotes on the main page (but not actually allow voting here) and finally sort these teasers by popularity (number of votes).

I can see that `print $content` is outputting this page's content but I am not sure where this is being generated so I can either hook into it or modify directly.  I've coded themes and plugins in Wordpress but I don't know Drupal well enough yet.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can find node.tpl.php inside your sites/all/themes/yourtheme folder. `$content` is generated in that file.